# Jquery:How to get the dynamic table td value?

Tags: jquery

Here is the table will look like:

```
<tr class="A" id="A${a.index}"> //id is generic like 1,2,3,4,5  
    <table id="mytable">
        <tr>
           <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>c</td>
             <td>d</td>
      </tr>
       </table>
   </tr>

I am creating a generic table using  <tr> id, based on generic <tr> id  I'm trying to get the td value
```

Here is the JS code I tried:

```
$('#mytable tr:nth-child(2) td').each(function(){
            alert($(this).text());
         });
```

The above  script will iterate all the td value in second tr, but i need to get only td value based on my parent tr id value(my tr id is dynamic it will be always changing) ,i am beginner to Jquery ,this table is generic so i am facing some difficult , kindly Can somebody help me to correct my code

Comment: @AnoopJoshi my parent tr is <tr class="A" id="A${a.index}">

Comment: @AnoopJoshi my <tr> id  value is dynamic it will be always changing

Comment: Will the the tr always be the second?

Comment: your markup is invalid, a `table` cannot be the immediate descendent of a `tr`

Comment: @JSelser yes the tr always second

Comment: So if I am not wrong, you want only those td whose text is same as table id?

Comment: @billyonecan , I agree your point but I am working exsting application ,it was developed like that only

Comment: @nikhil yes,I want only those td but td value also generic..

Comment: So how do you want to select the td's based on the tr id? Do the td's have a data attribute? Does the tr id need to match the td inner text as nikhil suggests?

Answer (score 0):

In case of dynamic markup you may use delegate:

```
$( "body" ).delegate( "#mytable tr:nth-child(2) td", "each", function() {
 alert($(this).text());
});
```

[jQuery delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. Check whether the text of table row column is same as the table containing row id

```
$('#mytable tr:nth-child(2) td').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() === $("#mytable").parent().attr("id")) {
        alert($(this).text());
    }
});
```